# Get Dynamic Members and SetValue from Interop Object

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit, system.reflection

I have this Interop Object that comes up as a System.__ComObject and I want to set values using a variable name:

```
SetValue(fieldname) = fieldvalue;
```

I also need to inspect the dynamic members to see what’s available. Some members (the ones ending  in Ref) have sub-members so I need to drill-down to them as well.

In debug,  the dynamic members come up as follows.  (sorry,i can't post the images)

http://www.mezzodev.com/qintegrator/download/debug1.png

http://www.mezzodev.com/qintegrator/download/debug2.png

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Impromptu Interface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) I was able gather the dynamic members with:

```
var memberNames = Impromptu.GetMemberNames(customerAdd, dynamicOnly:true);
```

Then I can set using a variable member name with:

```
string optField = "Phone";
string optValue = "818-555-1212";
Impromptu.InvokeGet(customerAdd,  optField).SetValue(optValue);
```

A big "Thank You!" to the developer of the [Impromptu Interface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) for answering this for me.